# UI Panels are not positioning themselves according to screen size

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, panel, android-canvas

My UI elements inside my panels are scaling fine with screen size, but the distance between my different panels is not. I have 3 panels in my scene at different relative position which i set at 1920x1080 reference resolution, and switching between them using animation. But when i change the game view resolution, these panels do not align themselves right. Here are the screenshots:

[image]
These are the panels at 1920x1080 which i set.

[image]
These are the panels when i set game view resolution to 2340x1080. As you can see, the "settings" panel is still fine but the "more settings" panel does not repositioned correctly.

[image]
The same thing happens when i set game resolution to 800x480.

Please help me..

Comment: Try using grid layout group.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can achieve what you are attempting to do is to use a component called [`GridLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html). Add this component to a parent object, child all three of your UI elements to it, and set the column count to 2.  I can add an example in a bit, currently building a project.

Edit: Here is a gif example of the above solution.

[image: Example gif]

Comment: i tried this, but not working properly. Everything is great at 1920x1080 which is my reference resolution as well as the cell size GridLayoutGroup, but when i change the resolution to say 2960x1440, my home page still have the 1920x1080 size and some part of "more settings" panel comes on screen. Am i doing something wrong??

Comment: @Shubh I have tested and it works fine for me at the resolutions you provided. Did you assure that your Canvas is set to scale and you provided a good `Reference Resolution` for your `Canvas`?